# What can I use to forward a conection to port 3006 on the bastion to an RDS database?

Tags: databases, ports

Forwarding a port 3006 database connection from a bastion server to a RDS database?

Trying to find the answer online I came across the term Proxy jump but can't find anything on proxy jump for 3006 to send a 3006 mysql conection to the bastion on port 3006 to an RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It is possible on the Linux(Unix) bastion host.***

Step-1: First ssh to the bastion host. *eg. 16.23.14.20 is the bastion host.*

```
# ssh root@16.23.14.20
```

Step-2: Create port tunneling by using the below command. eg. *The RDS IP is 172.16.13.10*

```
# ssh -L  3006:172.16.13.10:3006 localhost
```

Verify using netstat command.

```
netstat -ntulp | grep 3006
```

Note: If netstat command not available. Using `sudo apt install -y net-tools` or `sudo yum install -y net-tools`